# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Mi código hasta el momento:

```
<p><script language="javascript">
function funcion(){
    var a ="field_1";
    var b ="field_2";
    var c ="field_3";
    var d ="field_4";
    var e ="field_5";
    var f ="field_6";
    var g ="field_7";
    var aa = document.getElementById(a).value;
    var bb = document.getElementById(b).value;
    var cc = document.getElementById(c).value;
    var dd = document.getElementById(d).value;
    var ee = document.getElementById(e).value;
    var ff = document.getElementById(f).value;
    var gg = document.getElementById(g).value;
    $.post("Aqui va mi URL", { dni: aa, proc: bb, firma: cc, exp: dd, us: ee, "11": ff, "10": gg }, <br>function(data){
    $("#principal").html(data);
    });
}
window.onload = funcion;
```

Hasta ahí el JavaScript y el html es sencillo. Son 7 campos normales y corrientes.

Lo que estoy intentando, es que al enviar los datos a una pagina, esta los reenvie de nuevo. Osea la pagina 1 envia datos a la pagina2, y la pagina 2 mete en una base de datos y automaticamente los manda a la pagina 3

Me da el siguiente error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
>       at funcion
>       at window.onload

**¿Alguien tiene idea de por qué?**

Ese mismo código lo use anteriormente, solo modifique una o dos cositas. Aunque tampoco se que es esto `"$("#principal").html(data);"`. Le puse al formulario de ese nombre de ID por si acaso, quizas este mal.

Gracias por las molestias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando la función llega a ejecutarse jQuery no se ha cargado, por eso te dice "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined". Quizás en una de las ediciones que has realizado has borrado por error la etiqueta de carga de jQuery.

En cuanto a la segunda parte, con el siguiente código:

```
$("#principal").html(data);
```

lo que haría sería sustituir el formulario con los datos recibidos, lo cual probablemente no sea lo que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Te faltan los paréntesis de la función.

```
window.onload = funcion();
```

En cuanto a la parte de:

```
$("#principal").html(data);
```

Está añadiendo a un ID llamado "principal" el contenido de "data".